# Navigation scroll to matched elment in list items

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Hi I Am new to native script. While learning native script I faced a problem that, I have a-z letters and list items side by side. When I tap any item in (a-z), list view must move to matched first letter in list items. Same as contact filter using alphabets. Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using the Nativescript-UI `RadListView` because of the tag you added to the question.

You can use the scrollToIndex:

```
let listView: RadListView = <RadListView>(frameModule.topmost().currentPage.getViewById("listView"));

listView.scrollToIndex(50, false);
```

Where 50 is the index of the item you want to scroll to and false is wether you want to animate the scroll or not.